# Float left for first-level children for all tags destroy default display value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to set `float:left` for all first-level children, but after adding this style elements with `display:inline/inline-block/ other not block`  followed by `#root` selector after adding have default value for display = `display:block`; elements added before `#root` have standart default display value.

```
#root > * {
     float:left;
}
```

---

```
<div id="root">
    <div></div>
<div>
```

---

```
var aBefore = document.createElement("a");
var aAfter = document.createElement("a");
var root = document.getElementById("root");

document.body.insertBefore(aBefore,root);
root.appendChild(aAfter);

display(aBefore);
display(aAfter);

function display(element){
    alert(window.getComputedStyle(element).display);
}
```

### Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/LpQ5V/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Giving an element a `float` value inherently implies `display: block`.

The [operative portion of the spec:](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-float)

> The element generates a block box that is floated to the left.

*edit* —  Esailija correctly points out that `display: none` will in fact hide a floated element :-)

*edit again* — what I said above is probably something of an oversimplification. It's not so much that `float` forces `display: block`; it's that it causes an effect that *means the same thing as* `display: block` for the element.  It really only applies/works–for elements that are "box" elements anyway (according to the spec).  I haven't done exhaustive empirical testing to see whether floating a `<span>` or `<em>` element would do anything at all.

Comment: Does it really? I did not know that. I usually end up manually setting it to block. So the browser actually changed a floated element to block?

Comment: @Leeish no.. would an element with `display: none;` show up as block when floated?

Comment: @Leeish well it's more like the `display` property just becomes irrelevant, because it's always a block. It would be kind-of weird otherwise given the behavior of floats.

Comment: Obviously if you set an element to display: none, that would override an inherit. But if I float a span would that change the span to a block? Apparently. I've always been adding the display: block to non-block elements, not knowing float did this for me.

Comment: @Leeish well that's not clear; I should probably clarify the answer.  (It *might*, but it might not.)

Comment: Certain other properties like padding do no behave the same with block elements vs inline elements. I am going to mess with things to see how this actually works. I am assuming that if a float implies a block, then other properties like padding would act as if the element is a block and not a inline.

Comment: @Leeish yes, but that'll be the case only if `float: left` (or right) does anything at all with otherwise "inline" elements. (Maybe it's only natively block elements?  I'm not sure.)